# Почему размер изображения выводимый в консоль (посредством Bitmap) отличается от реального?

Tags: bitmap

Изображение "R.drawable.one" имеет разрешение 10х10, но при выводе в консоль кажет 35х35, с чем это связано и как преобразовать размер в реальный ?

```
    val im: ImageView = findViewById(R.id.img)
    val bit = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.one)
    im.setImageBitmap(bit)

    val h = bit.height
    val w = bit.width   

    Log.d("log", "size: $h $w")
```

out:
2021-06-22 18:47:59.349 7955-7955/ru.denis.bitmaptest D/log: size: 35 35

Comment: потому что есть реальные пиксели, а есть видимые https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities

Comment: спасибо милый человек, нашел для себя ответ там! Для других на всякий поясню детали, в моем случае система масштабировала изображение под конкретное устройство, что бы этого не происходило, необходимо изображение размещать в директории -> res\drawable-nodpi\